# C# - Rounding Down to Nearest Integer

Tags: c#

I have a C# app that is calculating some numbers. I need to round down.

```
var increment = 1.25;
var result = 50.45 - 23.70;    // equals 26.75
int interval = difference / increment; // result is 21.4. However, I just want 21
```

I have to get the `interval` to an `int`. At the same time, I cannot just use `Convert.ToInt32` because of its [rounding behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffdk7eyz.aspx). I always want the lowest whole number. However, I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Just try this..

```
 int interval = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(different/increment));
```

Comment: what if this is a double and you have 1e300 numbers? :)

Answer (score 33):

You can also just simply cast the result to `int`. This will truncate the number.

```
int interval = (int)(difference / increment);
```

Comment: Yes, this is the fastest option.

Comment: Note, this is only equivalent for positive numbers. Converting to int will bring the value _towards zero_. If you want `-1.1` to round _down_ to `-2`, you need `Math.Floor()`.

Comment: Depending on the range this is solved by adding a large constant to keep things positive, doing the cast and subtracting the same constant.

Answer (score 31):

Use the static `Math` class:

```
int interval = (int)Math.Floor(difference/increment);
```

`Math.Floor()` will round down to the nearest integer.

Comment: It returns a double = so why is there no compiler warning?

Comment: @Rob Just casting it to an `int` should do the trick, the documentation is a bit confusing "The largest integer less than or equal to d." but it does indeed return a double

Answer (score 9):

The `Math.Floor()` function should do the trick:

```
int interval = (int)Math.Floor(difference / increment);
```

See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/e0b5f0xb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx