# How can I round down the value of a double divided by an int?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
Double secsSinceLastCheck = AS.pointsDate - DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
Int32 prt = AS.prt.Val();

var reducePoints = secsSinceLastCheck / prt;
```

What I would like is for reducePoints to be an integer rounded down from the value on the right of the equation.

Comment: `(int) Math.Floor(secsSinceLastCheck/prt)`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Rounding Down to Nearest Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409965/c-sharp-rounding-down-to-nearest-integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
int reducePoints = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(secsSinceLastCheck / Convert.ToDouble(prt)));
```